# What is the purpose of the middle-man actor in chaffing and winnowing?

Tags: algorithm-design

Chaffing and winnowing is presented as a form of confidentiality without using encryption. This is beneficial for countries where encryption is regulated.

Below is a diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaffing_and_winnowing) showing Alice sending "1001" to Bob.

[image: Chaffing and winnowing]

My question is what is the purpose of Charles in this picture? Why can't Alice just chaff the data herself before sending it directly to Bob?

Additionally, if this assumes that traditional encryption methods aren't available, how are Alice and Charles talking over a secure channel?

Comment: Alice and Charles can be in the same building and secure the channel the old fashioned way, by locking the door. If Alice is adding the chaff it could be seen as an encryption algorithm that works by adding a lot of padding.

Answer (score 2):

Ron Rivest proposed this technique as a way of dealing with export restrictions as well as giving some protection to the parties communicating. It was roughly at the time of the Clipper chip debate. It is not encryption but gives confidentiality.

Pre shared symmetric keys is assumed to exist between Alice and Bob so the MAC tags can be checked at the destination to verify what's chaff.

Charles adds chaff independently so that confidentiality is achieved but Law Enforcement can't obtain "keys" from Alice or Bob to break the confidentiality.

Note that the keys supply authentication (NOT confidentiality) as is the normal purpose for the MAC.

Read more at [Rivest's homepage](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Chaffing.txt)

Comment: How does this help prevent law enforcement from obtaining keys from Alice or Bob? The same keys still have to be used, right?

Comment: See update, the document I linked to is only a few pages and well worth reading, barely longer than the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Having read a lot of that paper (still reading, you're right about it being good!) it seems Rivest's original intent for Charles in this case is to be a third party agent so chaff appearing is less suspicious (or at least, less accountable). The intent of my question is to ask, `is there any cryptographic reason why Charles is a part of this?` To which I believe the answer is `No, it's only for legal/deniability reasons`. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

The reason Charles is another party is simply for authority reasons.
The entire point of chaffing and winnowing was that it is *authentication NOT encryption* and would therefor be exempt from government regulations.

However chaffing and winnowing is more than authentication because chaff is now being added.

But Alice and Bob don't have to add the chaff themselves but could simply be communicating over an authenticated channel with Charles adding the chaff. Alice and Bob behave exactly the same and only want to communicate over an authenticated channel.

So, if an authenticated channel is permitted then chaffing and winnowing must be permitted as well because the two parties aren't necessarily involved in it.

At least that is my interpretation of https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Chaffing.txt